# is it binary compatible for emdebian and android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, binary-compatibility, scratchbox

the Android ndk is hard to use for the old autoconf based code, so i employed scratchbox2/emdebian to have a complete build environment. can i build a shared library in  emdebian (arch is armel) and then use it in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official NDK comes with a version of GCC that works with Google's custom Bionic libc.  If you are using a version of GCC that is intended to work with the GNU libc then you must statically link it in (as is done by the [Crystax NDK](http://www.crystax.net/android/ndk-r3.php)).  So even if your compiler generates the correct instructions, it may be worthwhile to rework your build environment to avoid bloating your application unnecessarily.

Comment: thanx. i donnot think static link is an option, find this http://github.com/tmurakam/droid-wrapper/. will see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

armel is Arm Eabi. Android is ARMv5 eABI. They will probably be compatible.